# dependant probability - balls out of a box...

Tags: probability

I've got a box with balls in it: 30 of them are black and 5 are white. The balls are handed out:

What's the probability that the first 5 balls taken out are black and the first white ball to be taken out is the 6th?

The only idea I had was something like:

30/35 x 29/34 x 28/33 x 27/32 x 26/31 x 5/30

But I don't know why, it looks wrong...

Comment: Your answer looks ok to me, assuming you are not replacing the balls.

Comment: No one said it looks wrong... just me. It looks weird. You're kidding me, that's the correct answer? I thought I'd have to use nPr or something...